# CSS Bootstrap - Mobile Navigation slide in from the right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap for my website navigation, but I was looking at this mobile version of this website: http://www.levelone.ca/ and I like how their navigation slides in from the right.

Is it possible to do this with bootstrap or will I have use another plugin to get that style?

Here is my bootstrap navigation:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Who We Are <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">What We Do <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/home-renovation/">Homes Renovation</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/custom-home/">Custom Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/project-management/">Project Management</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/condo-renovations/">Condo Renovations</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/luxury-features/">Luxury Features</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/our-projects/">Our Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Our Insight <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inspiration Board</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/our-process/">Our Process</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible to create something like this on your own (Bootstrap itself has no native component for this) and without a plugin. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

By default bootstrap doesn't provide your expected behaviour for mobile menu. But you can override the styles provided by bootstrap using CSS.